# Import "pandas" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

Tags: python, pandas, import, module, pip

I've already tried many tutorials on installing pandas. It actually worked the first time I used it, but the second time in a separate file, it doesn't work.

I've also already installed pandas through pip installer, and have uninstalled and reinstalled python.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you on and which Python version are you using? After **"many tutorials"** your system is likely messed up and you need to completely remove Python first. Then for installing pandas stick to the official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html

Answer (score 0):

visual studio code solution: You can fix this by going into settings then resetting python.defaultInterpreterPath